# Angular 2 compiled ahead of time gives error "A platform with a different configuration has been created."

Tags: angularjs, angular2-aot

I'm trying to figure out this whole [compile Ahead-of-Time](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) idea. I'm sold on the benefits but the process of actually doing it is giving me a headache.

I'm following the cookbook as close as possible. Probably the only big differences is that their `main.ts` is my `boot.ts` but my `boot.ts` is literally cut and paste of their `main.ts`. I have everything they say to install and the following tasks in my package.json:

```
"ngc": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json",
"rollup": "rollup -c rollup-config.js",
"copy-dist-files": "node build-scripts/copy-dist-files.js",
"aot": "npm run ngc && npm run rollup && npm run copy-dist-files"
```

tsconfig-aot.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "inlineSourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "pretty": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "aot",
    "skipMetadataEmit" : true
  }
}
```

rollup-config.js:

```
import rollup from 'rollup';
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import uglify from 'rollup-plugin-uglify';

export default {
  entry: 'aot/app/boot.js',
  dest: 'aot/app/bundle.js', // output a single application bundle
  moduleName: 'aot', // no idea what I'm SUPPOSED to put here, the rollup complained without it though
  sourceMap: false,
  format: 'iife',
  plugins: [
      nodeResolve({jsnext: true, module: true}),
      commonjs({
        include: 'node_modules/rxjs/**',
      }),
      uglify()
  ]
}
```

My `copy-dist-files.js` is just a node script to move my css and images into place in `aot/` and seems to be working just fine across all platforms. Honestly nothing about that file is really angular specific. If you need it I'll post it but I'm trying to keep things clean.

After I run `npm run aot` it completes successfully and I run `http-server aot` to serve up the folder and I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: A platform with a different configuration has been created. Please destroy it first.
```

An error I've never received using JiT compilation. I have no idea where this came from. Everytime I google it I find people asking about it relating to testing but this is about the bundle running in-browser. Those questions skirt around the actual error text because the issue is with [their testing scaffolding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136782/angular-2-issues-running-component-tests). I don't think I'm loading any other platform and I don't know how to destory it. What's especially odd is that the site seems to run and function completely normally.

Not uglifying the bundle.js doesn't help because the error seems to be thrown inside Angular's innards in portions I didn't write and would rather not edit.

I'm running Angular 2.1.1 and the error is showing in all browsers. What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out and sadly because I didn't understand the process I was working on I didn't give enough information in the question.

I was defining my module AND bootstrapping it in the same file (`boot.ts`) so when I followed the cookbook and created a `boot-aot.ts` that pointed to my old `boot.ts` there were still references and calls to `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic` (specific to JIT) and then there were calls to `@angular/platform-browser` (specific to AOT). This is how there were two platforms created.

The fix was to define my module in `module.ts` and have two ultra simple boots:

boot.ts:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch((err: any) => console.error(err));
```

and boot-aot.ts:

```
import { platformBrowser }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from '../aot/app/module.ngfactory';

platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory)
  .catch((err: any) => console.error(err));
```

`boot.ts` will be used for JIT compiling during debugging and `boot-aot.ts` is referenced in the `rollup-config.js`.